# Some parts of datatable is missing in table loaded using PartialView

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, partial-views, datatables

I have a view in my mvc application. According to selection of dropdown menu. With ajax, data table is loaded using PartialView.

However, Next, Previous buttons or search box does not seen in the table. The style of table does not load properly.

here is my codes

in my main view;

```
<div id="tablo">
   @{ Html.Partial("TestTable", Model); }
</div>
```

My Partial View;

```
<table class="dynamicTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Part</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.allparts.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.allparts[i].PartName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cant see any html markup for buttons in your main view or partial. If the partial is generated based on select list, main view would arguably be the best place to include these buttons

Comment: when i use that table class in my regular view, those buttons automatically loaded due to my class of table. But same buttons on the same class does not load when i move my <table> to partial view.